# SQL - selecting single occurrences

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table

| id1 | id2 | id3 | v2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | x | 1 | A |
| P1 | x | 2 | A |
| P1 | x | 3 | A |
| P2 | y | 1 | B |
| P2 | y | 2 | B |
| P3 | z | 1 | A |

and I would like to get the following:

| v2 | count_v2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2 |
| B | 1 |

I tried the following code, but it counts all occurrences in v2:

```
select v2, count(v2) from table_A group by id2
```

Comment: could you please specify what records you do not want to count?

Comment: Sure. So, basically I have three time P1 and x, but I would like to count this as one A. I have two time P2 and y, but I would like to count this as one B. And one time, P3 and z, wich I would like to count as one A. So in total 2 A and 1 B.I hope this clarifies my question.

Comment: @TRK I think no. From your explanation you should get as result A 1 and B 1, but in table you showed A 2 anb B 1.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to select the distinct count of `id1` for every `v2` group:

```sql
SELECT v2, COUNT(DISTINCT id1) AS count_v2
FROM table_A
GROUP BY v2;
```